# Mapping comma-separated list to values in abother sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am trying to create various numeric values to better track my work rather than simply based on hours, i.e. a particular category of work is assigned more "points" than another category of work based on some subjective difficulty. I've, therefore, created a Google Sheets spreadsheet but to calculate all this.

I have two spreadsheets, one for my main data and the other being a reference spreadsheet where I could list categories and associated grades (and points) which would hopefully work with the main spreadsheet. To better describe this, I've attached some pictures.

In the first sheet, **Sheet A**, I have two columns, **Work Points** and **Work Categories** as follows:

[image: Points/Categories]

And a reference spreadsheet, **Sheet B**, as follows:

[image: Reference Spreadsheet]

What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

1. Based on the comma-separated list in the **Work Categories** column in Sheet A, split these and map them to their respective **Task** in the reference spreadsheet.

Each **Task** has an associated **Grade** and each **Grade** and associated number of points in the **Points** column, therefore,

2. Each mapped **Task** would have an associated **Grade** which would then map to the **Points** column.
3. Sum the points based on the values mapped to the comma-separated list and fill a single value for that sum in the **Work Points** column of the original row (where the formula would be written).

It should be noted that entries in the **Work Categories** column can be of variable length.

Is this something that is currently possible in Google Sheets? Alternatively, I could use Excel if this is something that is wildly different across platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B10="",,MMULT(IFERROR(
 VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SPLIT(B2:B10, ",")), D:E, 2, ), G:H, 2, ), 0), 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(B2:B10, ",")), 1, 1, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly provided the columns are in the same sheet. I tried to reference my "SheetB" by replacing "D:E" with "SheetB!D:SheetB!E" but this doesn't seem to work. Do you happen to know how this would be extended to enable cross-referencing the sheets?

Comment: @AlexanderPugantsov `D:E` becomes `SheetB!D:E`